# Independent Scroll Bars for a CSplitterWnd? (MFC)

Tags: c++, mfc, scrollbar, csplitterwnd

I have an application that allows the user to select Split Window from a dropdown menu, displaying the current document in two adjacent client areas using a CSplitterWnd CreateStatic call.

I've found much documentation on creating a shared scroll bar, but what I want is two, independently scrolling bars.

How do I proceed?

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The two client area windows can each scroll independently if they are designed to scroll. In MFC that normally means they should each be derived from CScrollView. They operate the same way whether they are within a splitter or not.